# WHat is the first T in this c# method signature?

Tags: c#

```
public static T MyMethod<T>()
```

The `<T>` refers to a type, right? But what is the first `T` doing?

Comment: Stating that it is the type of the return value from this method.

Comment: I think we need some more answers here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining language fundamentals is too broad a subject for SO. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith Hehe. When someone throws out a bunny like this, people jump all over it. 3 answers appeared before I could even finish typing mine. =)

Comment: This is the first C# question I saw on SO as I don't know the language! But man, it has left a ever lasting effect on me! 2 visibly similar questions get +8 and -1 ... DaHell! ... C# is indeed interesting

Comment: @BhargavRao: many of the down voted answers were edited after the down votes were cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `T` is the return type of the method.

Comment: Thats what I thought the <T> was doing.  So what is the second T then?

Comment: @teahou: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's a generic method and first T will be the return type of that method

Answer (score 1):

T is the type that method is going to return.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the method.

Comment: this could be a comment

Answer (score -1):

This is defined a generic method. The `T` refers to the type that your method will return.

For instance if we say that you call this method
 like below:

```
className.MyMethod<int>()
```

this method will return an `int`. The className is the name of the class in you have defined this static generic method.

Answer (score -2):

It's the return type. You're saying that the type specified when the method is called will be returned. So calling mymethod with an int specifier in the generic, will return an int.